# Can you create preaggregated Dimensions/Measuresments like OLAP in BigQuery with Tableau?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api, olap

During the Cloud Migration of an On-Premise Microsoft SQL DB, the OLAP Cube, which is part of it, should also be replaced (but not migrated directly). There is the business requirement to keep the functionality in Tableau that you can select different measurements and dimension with their corresponding aggregations, as is possible now when connecting to the OLAP Cube in Tableau.

The underlying Data Source View includes ca. 10 tables (e.g. customer, sales, payment-method, customer-segmentation, time). So via OLAP the analysis "give me the average sales per payment method per customer-segment for every week" is a couple of clicks, in pure SQL it's already some effort.

How can you offer defined aggregations for some BigQUery tables without the user having to write the joins and aggregations by themselves, mainly because it takes much more time than simply drag & drop (SQL skills & time of query-execution are not the issue)?

Comment: Without explaining your need through an example, only the persons knowing both can answer your question.  I feel you are looking for LOD calculations in Tableau which can aggregate measures without the need of precalculation and then join with main table.  I am not aware of bigquery that's I am not sure and not posting a detailed answer.  Please include a bare minimal example to explain your need.

Comment: The philosophy of having pre-aggregated measurements or dimensions in OLAP cubes is based on the slowness of queries in standard databases. The downside is that only the pre-defined aggregates are present, limiting the versatility of interactive analysis. Modern analytics-focussed databases (like BigQuery) use different database approaches (like columnstore indexing) to make arbitrary aggregate queries much faster, avoiding the need to precalculate results. So you might find that pre-aggregation is not needed at all.

Comment: The goal is to still have all this data pre-aggregated not because it's needed, but because the user can select from a distinct set of options, e.g. the average order amount (measurement) for every payment method (rows) in the different stores (columns). This "PowerPivot" like behavior makes it much faster than having the user first join the tables and calculating the average. In the Cube definition I can prepare these measurements & combinations. I would like to do that in Tableau / prepare it for Tableau usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turns out to be pretty straight forward:

Join all source data together and write it into one flat table in BigQuery which includes the same information as the data source view in the OLAP Cube. Then Tableau connects to this table. The "measurements" logic from the cube is implemented as calculations in Tableau, the table columns are the dimensions.

Some caution needs to be applied when replicating the measurements because 1:n relations in the Data Source View result in multiplied data in the flat table. This can be solvedwith the correct use of Distinct Functions (e.g. "Distinct Count") in the measurement definition.

The table will end up quite large, but the queries on it are very fast, resulting in a performance increase compared to the OLAP Cube with the same user experience as using a cube in Tableau.

Comment: Big, flat, denormalised tables are very fast to query on analytics databases. But you can't just join everything: you need to think carefully about the structure of the join so that the resulting table has exactly the right level of detail per row. This, as you say, requires care but it can be done without too much effort.